# Vertically align 'Bigdelim' delimiters

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, multirow, bigdelim

I have a table where I would like to associate a few entries using the Bigdelim package. However, I cannot figure out how to get the delimiters to align. I have one table which, by chance, has the same entry in each cell and so the delimiters line up nicely:
[image: The ideal result]

However, my other table is not so lucky, and comes out looking like this:
[image: The problem]

The code I have so far looks like this:

```
\documentclass{report}      % use "amsart" instead of "article" for AMSLaTeX format
\usepackage{geometry}                       % See geometry.pdf to learn the layout options. There are lots.
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

%Maths
\usepackage{amssymb}

% Chemistry packages
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\chemsetup{formula=mhchem}

% Table settings
\usepackage{array}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\newcolumntype{e}[1]{D{.}{.}{4.1}}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\newcommand{\mc}{\multicolumn}
\newcommand{\mr}{\multirow}

\usepackage{bigdelim}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
        \caption{Example of the issue}
        \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{l *6{e{-2}}}
            \toprule
            \mc{1}{c}{\mr{2}{*}{Assignment}}    &   \mc{2}{c}{Exp.} &   \mc{2}{c}{Column 1} &   \mc{2}{c}{Column 2} \\
            \cmidrule(lr){2-3}  \cmidrule(lr){4-5}  \cmidrule(lr){6-7}
                &   \mc{1}{Y}{\ce{\nu}} &   \mc{1}{Y}{\ce{\Delta\nu}}   &   \mc{1}{Y}{\ce{\nu}} &   \mc{1}{Y}{\ce{\Delta\nu}}   &   \mc{1}{Y}{\ce{\nu}} &   \mc{1}{Y}{\ce{\Delta\nu}}   \\
            \midrule
            \ldelim\{{2}{*}[\ce{2\nu2}] &       &   293 &   3112    &   32.2    &   23  &   0.00    \\
                &       &   34  &   22.22   &   2   &   1   &   669 \\
            \ldelim\{{2}{*}[\ce{\nu1}]  &   231 &   -1232   &   1232    &   232.2   &   0.0 &   3   \\
                &       &   31223   &   33.4    &   -35.1   &   221.4   &   -30.2   \\
            \ce{\nu2}   &   1.5 &   +21.5   &   120.0   &   +7.7    &   10.9    &   +121.6  \\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[h]
        \caption{Example of the ideal.}
        \label{tbl:h2s-tma}
        \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{l c *6{e{-2}}}
            \toprule
            \mc{2}{c}{\mr{2}{*}{Assignment}}    &   \mc{2}{c}{Exp.} &   \mc{2}{c}{Column 1} &   \mc{2}{c}{Column 2} \\
                        \cmidrule(lr){3-4}  \cmidrule(lr){5-6}  \cmidrule(lr){7-8}
                &       &   \mc{1}{Y}{\ce{\nu}} &   \mc{1}{Y}{\ce{\Delta\nu}}   &   \mc{1}{Y}{\ce{\nu}} &   \mc{1}{Y}{\ce{\Delta\nu}}   &   \mc{1}{Y}{\ce{\nu}} &   \mc{1}{Y}{\ce{\Delta\nu}}   \\
            \midrule
            \mr{3}{*}{\ce{2\nu2}}   &   \ldelim\{{3}{*}[$A_1$]  &   2   &       &       &       &       &       \\
                &       &   241.0   &       &       &       &       &       \\
                &       &   24  &       &   2415.6  &   +629    &   2.8 &   +34.8   \\
            \mr{2}{*}{\ce{\nu1}}    &   \ldelim\{{2}{*}[$A_1$]  &   2324.00 &   -261.3  &       &       &       &       \\
                &       &   234.9   &   -80.1   &   24.4    &   -1360.2 &   224.5   &   -312.1  \\
            \ce{\nu2} & $A_1$   &   12.9    &   +203.9  &   155.9   &   +7.6    &   1.6 &   +112.3  \\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Does anyone know how I could align the brackets in Table 1 vertically, so they look like Table 2? Also, is there a way to align all the different A1's? I just noticed that the brackets have pushed the top two out of alignment...

(On a side note, is there any way to make the brackets a little more separated? I would rather they weren't touching each other in Table 2, if possible, but that's just a stylistic preference...)

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  Regarding table 1, you could cheat and put `\phantom{2} in front of `\nu1`.  (I'm not in a position to test for separation between the braces.  I'm sure my first thought won't work.)

Comment: Off-topic: It looks like you're (ab-)using the `\ce` macro of the `mhchem` package to typeset ordinary math material. E.g., `\ce{\Delta\nu}` instead of `$\Delta\nu$`. Sooner or later (likely sooner...), such a choice is going to come back to haunt you. Please switch to employing standard notation for inline math material.

Comment: @Mico I use `\ce` as a habit because most of these things are specifically chemistry related (these are vibrational transitions). Maths mode is generally my default for non-chemistry related things, though

Answer (score 3):

With `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix` and the columns `S` of `siunitx` (the columns `d` of `dcolumn` are not supported by `nicematrix`).

In `nicematrix`, there is a built-in command `\SubMatrix` which may be used to draw the braces.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{geometry} 
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{booktabs}


\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\caption{Example of the issue}
\begin{NiceTabular}{l *6{S}}
\toprule
\Block{2-1}{Assignment} & \Block{1-2}{Exp.} && \Block{1-2}{Column 1} && \Block{1-2}{Column 2} & \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-3}  \cmidrule(lr){4-5}  \cmidrule(lr){6-7}
 & {$\nu$} & {$\Delta\nu$} & {$\nu$} & {$\Delta\nu$} & {$\nu$} & {$\Delta\nu$} \\
\midrule
\Block{2-1}{$2\nu_2$} & & 293 & 3112 & 32.2 & 23 & 0.00 \\
 & & 34 & 22.22 & 2 & 1 & 669 \\
\Block{2-1}{$\nu_1$} & 231 & -1232 & 1232 & 232.2 & 0.0 & 3 \\
 & & 31223 & 33.4 & -35.1 & 221.4 & -30.2 \\
$\nu_2$ & 1.5 & +21.5 & 120.0 & +7.7 & 10.9 & +121.6  \\
\bottomrule
\CodeAfter [sub-matrix/xshift=1cm]
  \SubMatrix{\{}{3-2}{4-7}{.}
  \SubMatrix{\{}{5-2}{6-7}{.}
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

As usual with `nicematrix`, you need several compilations.

[image: Output of the above code]

In `{NiceTabular}`, it's not possible to define columns with features of both `X` and `S` (of `siunitx`) columns. However, it's possible to use `{NiceTabular*}`. That environment corresponds to the environment `{tabular*}` of standard LaTeX.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{geometry} 
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\caption{Example of the issue}
\begin{NiceTabular*}{\textwidth}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}SSSSSS}
\toprule
\Block{2-1}{Assignment} & \Block{1-2}{Exp.} && \Block{1-2}{Column 1} && \Block{1-2}{Column 2} & \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-3}  \cmidrule(lr){4-5}  \cmidrule(lr){6-7}
 & {$\nu$} & {$\Delta\nu$} & {$\nu$} & {$\Delta\nu$} & {$\nu$} & {$\Delta\nu$} \\
\midrule
\Block{2-1}{$2\nu_2$} & & 293 & 3112 & 32.2 & 23 & 0.00 \\
 & & 34 & 22.22 & 2 & 1 & 669 \\
\Block{2-1}{$\nu_1$} & 231 & -1232 & 1232 & 232.2 & 0.0 & 3 \\
 & & 31223 & 33.4 & -35.1 & 221.4 & -30.2 \\
$\nu_2$ & 1.5 & +21.5 & 120.0 & +7.7 & 10.9 & +121.6  \\
\bottomrule
\CodeAfter [sub-matrix/xshift=1cm]
  \SubMatrix{\{}{3-2}{4-7}{.}
  \SubMatrix{\{}{5-2}{6-7}{.}
\end{NiceTabular*}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the second code]

Comment: This looks like a really good option (I wish I'd known about `nicematrix` before!), but there's one issue. I'm using `tabularx` so that I can have all the columns of the table the same width. Someone came up with a sneaky way of combining `dcolumn` with `X` columns, where you use `\multicolumn{1}{X}{xx}` for a column heading, allowing you to align the entries by the decimal point _and_ maintain equal column widths. Is there any way to achieve the same thing with `nicematrix`? I read about `nicetabularx`, but can't find anything in the manual which combines S and X column characteristics

Comment: +1. You may want to replace `\ce{...}` with `$...$`, though, for a more standard use of inline math mode.

Comment: @Mico: You're right. I have modified my answer.